# System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorMap equivalent on .NET Compact Framework

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, system.drawing

I have a need to use a ColorMap object in .NET Compact Framework but from what I can tell it is not available.

Need some ideas on how to best workaround this limitation.

Comment: Chris, can you give us more details on what end-result you're trying to achieve (i.e. alphablending, transparency, etc)?  Maybe we can suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

it is discussed in msdn forum (it is not allowed for me to add links yet, but you can easily find it on the web)
This class is not supported by the .net compact framework. Would suggest using manual recoloring instead or using Reflector to obtain a code of ColorMap from .net framework and use it your code.

Answer (score 0):

The native IBitmapImage object does have a get/setpalette method, but I don't know if that's what you're looking for.

see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa911323(v=MSDN.10).aspx